# OSX Sierra font issue in Safari

Tags: macos, mac, fonts, safari, macos-sierra

Since updating to OSX Sierra I experience a font issue in Safari.
The other browsers and programs are OK.

[image: Screen-dump showing the described issue]

**What I found out, so far:**

- The boxed characters you see in my screen-dump are called the last
  resort font. That is always activated on OSX, as a last resort, for
  when there are no other font alternatives.
- This issue mostly appears    when people are using a font manager (I
  use FontExplorer X pro 2).

**Where I got stuck:**

The video link beneath explains this issue, plus the solution for Lion. 
The folders in Sierra are different, so from here I am stuck: 
I have not got the needed understanding of coding and the operating system to even know where I should be looking now.

[video about this issue, covering the solution for Lion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dW9aHlOIJUg)

Any tips, links, or explanations would be awesome, 
thanks!

Comment: Use another browser. Or try validating your Fontbook cache, clear the fontbook cache, etc.

Comment: Try - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42897/font-gets-replaced